# Is "church" one syllable or two?

Tags: pronunciation, speech, syllables

I read like twenty years ago that the word "church" (clutch, hatch, match) is undoubtedly one syllable when written but that an argument can be made that it's two syllables -- CHUR-ch -- when spoken.  Actually I don't think the book put it in such ambiguous terms as much as I've yet to find anyone who would so much as entertain the notion.

Does anyone know what book I'm talking about (perhaps a *Norton's Guide to...* type book) or have any insight into this phenomenon?  Like maybe a name for such a word?  Other examples?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, not if "luxury yacht" is pronounced "Luck-zhree yot".  :-)

Comment: So does that mean *churchyard*, *churchmen*, *matchbook*, and *hatchling* are three syllables? This is the problem with allotting two syllables to *church* and *match*.

Comment: @PeterShor - Yes, that would be terrible.

Comment: @PeterShor it doesn't mean that at all.  What you say does not logically or vocally follow from the original question. That, plus, why would you go to such a facile example in order to prove the question is beneath mere consideration.  I've acknowledged in the question that the answer might be ambiguous.  Your comment is "too clever by half" as the English speaking people say.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth interesting answer.  Maybe I'm not smart enough to get "depends on how you pronounce it."  

"Hey buddy, can you get me to the church on time?"
"Did you just ask me if you'd like to be punched in the face?"
"Oh sorry, maybe I pronounced it wrong."

Comment: I was trying to avoid the clear but blunt statement " 'is undoubtedly one syllable when written' doesn't make sense". It's like saying " 'church' is loud when written".

Comment: I didn't think I was just being clever. I think my comment at least shows that *church* is not always a two-syllable word. At best, it could be called a two-syllable word ***when it comes at the end of a phrase.*** So most of the time, it's a one-syllable word.

Comment: But [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvpDOgoN8GM) is good evidence that *church* is indeed two syllables at the end of a phrase. (And googling for youtube videos with the same children's game gives more evidence, although most aren't as funny as this one.)

Comment: Thank you both for your clarifications.  Good points!  RE: "duplicate answer" (not that anyone comes back and checks after marking questions thusly) I'm pretty sure "church" does not come under the category "tripthong" as it's a consonant and not vowel sound that adds the extra syllable.